# Laravel pusher Illuminate \ Broadcasting \ BroadcastException No message

Tags: laravel, pusher, broadcasting

I'am using Laravel 5.5 with pusher to make a real time notification , the notification made from the Api
after i made the configuration
in the Api

```
     public function store(Request $request)
    { 
         $advertising = Advertising::create($request->all()); 
         $admins = \App\Admin::all();
        \Notification::send( $admins, new \App\Notifications\AdvertisingAdded($advertising) );

         return $advertising;
    }
```

in AdvertisingAdded

```
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\BroadcastMessage;
use App\Advertising;

class AdvertisingAdded extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    //-must be public fir pusher
    public $advertising;

    public function __construct(Advertising $advertising)
    {
        $this->advertising = $advertising;
    }


    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database','broadcast'];
    }


    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'msg' => 'Advertising '.$this->advertising->title_ar.' is added ',
            'advertising_id' => $this->advertising->id
        ];
    }

    public function toBroadcast($notifiable)
    {
        return new BroadcastMessage([
            'msg' => 'Advertising '.$this->advertising->title_ar.' is added ',
            'advertising_id' => $this->advertising->id
        ]);
    }
}
```

when i post from postman i get an error

> Illuminate \ Broadcasting \ BroadcastException No message
>   [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LU4k0.png)

i followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i6Rdkv-DLwk

Answer (score 13, accepted):

i solve my problem by : making the   encrypted: false

Comment: Also had this problem but for some reason I'd still get the error even after setting encryption to false. Solved it by resetting the cache (php artisan config:cache)

Comment: Worked for me :)
Not sure why it gives error on ecrypted: true

Answer (score 7):

Add curl options to broadcasting.php

```
`'pusher' => [
                'driver' => 'pusher',
                'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
                'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
                'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
                'options' => [
                    'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                    'encrypted' => true,
                    'curl_options' => [
                        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
                    ]
                ],`
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem. In config/broadcasting.php use this code

```
'options' => [
'cluster' => 'eu',
'useTLS' => false
],
```

make `useTLS` false

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 7, configured like below to config/broadcasting.php and and run artisan command cache:clear. solved for me.

```
'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => 'mt1',
            'useTLS' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

Answer (score -3):

I solved my problem by setting my .env file

Set:

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
DB_HOST=localhost
```

And run

```
php artisan config:cache
```