# Illuminate \ Broadcasting \ BroadcastException No message

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, websocket

I'm using [Laravel websocket written by beyoundcode](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets).

After couple of days, I've connected to `myDomain.com/laravel-websockets` and first step solved.

But now, when I trigger an **`event`**, laravel has error at this point:

```
/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/Broadcasters/PusherBroadcaster.php 
**at line 117-(in my case)-**
```

this is my stacktrace screenshot:

[image: stacktrace]

I read these questions and issues but nothing worked for me:

[Laravel Pusher exception: “Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastException”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48492853/laravel-pusher-exception-illuminate-broadcasting-broadcastexception)

[Exception: Illuminate \ Broadcasting \ BroadcastException No message in PusherBroadcaster.php:119](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55092732/exception-illuminate-broadcasting-broadcastexception-no-message-in-pusherbr)

[Laravel pusher Illuminate \ Broadcasting \ BroadcastException No message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47990690/laravel-pusher-illuminate-broadcasting-broadcastexception-no-message)

But none of them did help to me.

I saw these `issue` too:

[PusherBroadcaster exception "Failed to connect to Pusher" when running in queue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/16478)

and based on [this comment](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/16478#issuecomment-261796182), I updated my `php.ini` file with this:

```
[curl]
; A default value for the CURLOPT_CAINFO option. This is required to be an
; absolute path.
curl.cainfo ="/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt"

these options tested too:

curl.cainfo ="/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem"
curl.cainfo ="/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt"
```

I did test the scenario in localhost and everything seems to be good, I guess I have a problem with my ssl, so just for more detail I have to say I'm using a `vps` that use `linux centos7` and my control panel is `directadmin` and I used `letsencrypt` with my control panel to use `https`.

Does anyone you know what's my problem?

***Thanks in Advance***

Comment: You got solution ? facing same issue tried everything mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In my case, the problem was solved when I put my `cert keys` to a
> ***path which apache could access*** to those files.

I did add curl options array with these values:

```
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
            'encrypted' => true,
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => 6001,
            'scheme' => 'https',
            'curl_options' => [
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
            ]
```

> **And then do not forget to**:
>
> php artisan cache:clear
>
> php artisan config:clear

Hope this heal your headache because did mine.